# Динамическое обновление данных на странице

Tags: python, bootstrap

Есть простой проект python flask, стоящий на raspberry. Я считываю температуру и  влажность с датчика, и вывожу их на boostrap страничку. Все выводится отлично, но приходится обновлять страничку, чтобы данные обновлялись. Подскажите как сделать, чтобы температура и влажность обновлялись динамически?

Код python:

```
from flask import *
from main_my import *

app = Flask(__name__)

pump_sost = None

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<name>')
  def main(name=None):
  humidity = humidityPi()
  temperature = tempPi()
  global pump_sost

  hid = {'hid': humidity}
  temp = {'temp': temperature}
  print(temp)

  if name == 'pomp1':
    rely(0x15, 13, 0x1)
    pump_sost = 'Включен'
  elif name == 'pomp2':
    rely(0x15, 13, 0x0)
    pump_sost = 'Выключен'

pumpSost = {'pumpSost': pump_sost}

led_val = '100'
led(led_val)


return render_template("index.html", title='My Ferma', pumpSost=pumpSost, hid=hid, temp=temp, name=name,)


if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(host='localhost', port=9090)
```

Блок bootstrap где вывожу данные:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top: 10px">
        <h1 class="display-4">Моя ферма</h1>
        <p class="lead">Это простой пример блока с компонентом в стиле 
jumbotron для привлечения дополнительного внимания к содержанию или 
информации.</p>
        <hr class="my-4">
        <p class="display-4">Темпертура: {{ temp.temp }}<br>Влажность: {{ 
hid.hid }}%</p>
        <p class="lead">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
href="http://localhost:9090/" role="button">Обновить</a>
        </p>
        <span id="doc_time">
         Дата и время
        </span>
    </div>
```

**UPD:** Нашел пример Ajax Request https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721679/update-and-render-a-value-from-flask-periodically

Добавил метод Get:

```
@app.route('/<name>', methods= ['GET'])
```

Где bootstrap добавил скрипт:

```
function update_values() {
        $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT+"/<name>",
            function(data) {
                $("#temp").text(data.temp+" %")
                $("#hid").text(data.hid+" %")
            });
    }
```

Но не обновляет, bootstrap разметку оставил как было, наверное там тоже нужно сослаться на функцию?

Comment: Безотносительно flask/bootstrap: вариантов два, либо периодически обновлять часть страницы с помощью ajax (т.н. *ajax polling*, есть вариант *long-polling*), либо открывать двусторонний канал по обмену сообщениями между сервером и вебстраничкой, приобновлении данных сервер шлет их клиенту (*websockets*). Примеров в интернете должно быть много, если поищешь по выделенным словам.

Comment: Нашел такой пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721679/update-and-render-a-value-from-flask-periodically
Но никак не получается соотнести с моим кодом. Попробовал вариант Ajax Request из примера, не обновляет.

Comment: Я в дороге, компьютера нет под рукой, чтобы набросать работающий вариант. Можешь добавить неработающий код в вопрос? Если никто не ответит, то как буду дома, напишу ответ с примером.

Comment: Спасибо за обратную связь, код добавил в вопрос.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Получилось сделать, оставлю ответ, может кому-то тоже поможет.

**Функция:**

```
 <script>
   setInterval(function()
   {
   $('#temp').load(document.URL +  ' #temp');
   $('#hid').load(document.URL +  ' #hid');
   }, 1000)
 </script>
```

**Блок bootstrap:**

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top: 10px">
    <h1 class="display-4">Моя ферма</h1>
    <p class="lead">Текст</p>
    <hr class="my-4">
    <div id='temp'>Температура: {{ temp.temp }}</div>
    <br>
    <div id='hid'>Влажность: {{ hid.hid}}</div>
    <p class="lead">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="http://localhost:9090/" 
    role="button">Обновить</a>
    </p>     
</div>
```

#updated!